# WPF sql server connection string error

Tags: sql-server, wpf, connection-string

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-OCSSDNA; Initial Catalog=Login; Connect Timeout = 00;");
con.Open();
```

Hi, this code is connection string my login form; but error message: Login failed for user ''. 
help please.
My sql have not user id and user password.

Comment: You can set Integrated Security=True in your connection string. Like this:
`Data Source=DESKTOP-OCSSDNA; Initial Catalog=Login; Connect Timeout = 00; Integrated Security=True;` When that is set to true, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.

Comment: if set Integrated Security=True after error message:Cannot open database "Login" requested by the login. The login failed.

Comment: Your user might not have rights to that database. Can you login locally? If so, could it be that you have a named instance, not the default SQL Server instance?

Comment: Server name: DESKTOP-OCSSDNA \ TEST
and windows authentication
database name: Login
table name: Registered

Do not you need to get in?

Comment: You also need to write the Data Source complete, with the instance name included. So your final connection string would be like this:
`Data Source=DESKTOP-OCSSDNA\TEST; Initial Catalog=Login; Connect Timeout = 00; Integrated Security=True;`

Comment: DESKTOP-OCSSDNA\TEST; error: unrecognized escape sequence

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments, you have a named instance. 
The last issue you have is coming up because you need to escape the '\':

Try the following, should work:

```
Data Source=DESKTOP-OCSSDNA\\TEST; Initial Catalog=Login; Connect Timeout = 00; Integrated Security=True;
```

For more information you could check [this](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/) article.

Comment: @"Data Source=DESKTOP-OCSSDNA\TEST; Initial Catalog=Login; Connect Timeout = 00; Integrated Security=True;" succesflly thanks.

Comment: yep, that as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-OCSSDNA; Initial Catalog=Login; Integrated Security=True";)
con.Open();
```